# CMake generated MSVC project cannot find symbols even if lib files are correctly generated for their correlated dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I've been bashing my head against this problem for the last few days (my repo is linked down below). I want CMake to generate a MSVC solution for which the Engine project is linked to the Demo project. While the .lib and .dll files are correctly generated and added to the projects in MSVC, I still get unresolved linker symbol errors from the Demo project referencing symbols from the Engine project. The Engine.lib file is correctly added to Demo's dependencies, and so are the headers. I have no globals for which I'd need to use the generated exported headers. What's the issue here?

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(P_SentryAll)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

include(GenerateExportHeader)

# glob source and header files
file(GLOB_RECURSE EngineSources SENTRY.Engine/*.cpp SENTRY.Engine/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CoreSources SENTRY.Core/*.cpp SENTRY.Core/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE RenderSources SENTRY.Render/*.cpp SENTRY.Render/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE DemoSources SENTRY.Demo/*.cpp SENTRY.Demo/*.hpp)

file(GLOB_RECURSE EngineHeaders SENTRY.Engine/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE CoreHeaders SENTRY.Core/*.hpp)


add_subdirectory(SENTRY.Core)
add_subdirectory(SENTRY.Engine)
add_subdirectory(SENTRY.Render)
add_subdirectory(SENTRY.Demo)
```

Root/Sentry.Core/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# define project
project(P_SentryCore)

add_library(SentryCore SHARED ${CoreSources})
target_include_directories(SentryCore PUBLIC src/module)
generate_export_header(SentryCore)

install(TARGETS SentryCore DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${CoreHeaders} DESTINATION include/SentryCore)
```

Root/Sentry.Engine/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(P_SentryEngine)

add_library(SentryEngine SHARED ${EngineSources})
target_link_libraries(SentryEngine PUBLIC SentryCore)
target_include_directories(SentryEngine PUBLIC src/engine)
generate_export_header(SentryEngine)

install(TARGETS SentryEngine DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES ${EngineHeaders} DESTINATION include/SentryEngine)
```

Root/Sentry.Demo/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# define project
project(P_SentryDemo)

add_executable(SentryDemo ${DemoSources})
target_link_libraries(SentryDemo PUBLIC SentryEngine)
include_directories(SENTRY.Engine/src/engine SENTRY.Core/src/module)

# packaging
install(TARGETS SentryDemo DESTINATION build)
```

Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: SentryEngine, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>Engine.cpp
2>Auto build dll exports
2>   Creating library C:/Users/main/Desktop/Projects/SENTRY/Build/SENTRY.Engine/Debug/SentryEngine.lib and object C:/Users/main/Desktop/Projects/SENTRY/Build/SENTRY.Engine/Debug/SentryEngine.exp
2>SentryEngine.vcxproj -> C:\Users\main\Desktop\Projects\SENTRY\Build\SENTRY.Engine\Debug\SentryEngine.dll
3>------ Build started: Project: SentryDemo, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>SENTRY.Demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Engine<__int64,struct std::ratio<1,1000000> >::Init(void)" (?Init@?$Engine@_JU?$ratio@$00$0PECEA@@std@@@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
3>SENTRY.Demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Engine<__int64,struct std::ratio<1,1000000> >::Run(void)" (?Run@?$Engine@_JU?$ratio@$00$0PECEA@@std@@@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
3>SENTRY.Demo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl Engine<__int64,struct std::ratio<1,1000000> >::RegisterModule(class Module<__int64,struct std::ratio<1,1000000> > *)" (?RegisterModule@?$Engine@_JU?$ratio@$00$0PECEA@@std@@@@QEAAXPEAV?$Module@_JU?$ratio@$00$0PECEA@@std@@@@@Z) referenced in function main
3>C:\Users\main\Desktop\Projects\SENTRY\Build\SENTRY.Demo\Debug\SentryDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
3>Done building project "SentryDemo.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
4>------ Skipped Build: Project: INSTALL, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

[Repo](https://gitlab.com/livium/sentry)

Comment: Having repo with your code is nice, but Stack Overflow still **requires** the corresponded **code** to be **in the question post** itself. Please, fix that problem. For more info see [ask].

Comment: Along with the code, please add the **exact** error messages to your question post. It is difficult to speculate what the problem might be without seeing the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in `Root/Sentry.Demo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(SENTRY.Engine/src/engine SENTRY.Core/src/module)
```

appears to be incorrect. It uses relative paths, so I don't believe these are valid paths in your project:

```
Root/Sentry.Demo/SENTRY.Engine/src/engine
Root/Sentry.Demo/SENTRY.Core/src/module
```

Prefer to use **absolute** paths wherever possible, through use of the [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) variable. This variable provides the path to the top-level source directory. So try something like this instead:

```
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SENTRY.Engine/src/engine
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SENTRY.Core/src/module
)
```

---

I took another look at your repo, and perhaps more importantly, you must have the **full** definition of `Engine` template functions in the *header* file, not the source file.

So move these function definitions to the header file, within your `Engine` class definition:

```
template<typename T_rep, typename T_ratio>
void Engine<T_rep, T_ratio>::Init()
{
    for (auto& module_ : Modules)
    {
        module_->Init();
    }
}

template<typename T_rep, typename T_ratio>
void Engine<T_rep, T_ratio>::Run()
{
    RunUpdateLoop = true;
    auto TPStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto TPEnd = TPStart;

    while (RunUpdateLoop)
    {
        auto deltaT = TPEnd - TPStart;
        TPStart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        for (auto& module_ : Modules)
        {
            module_->Run((deltaT));
        }

        TPEnd = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
}

template<typename T_rep, typename T_ratio>
void Engine<T_rep, T_ratio>::RegisterModule(Module<T_rep, T_ratio>* ToRegister)
{
    Modules.push_back(ToRegister);
}
```

This should help get you on the right track.